# Return true is string contains specific character in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

Just learning JS and I'm trying to answer the following question: write a function that takes 2 inputs (string and character), uses a for loop and will return true if the character is found within the string.

Here is what I came up with:

```
var hasEl = function(str, char) {
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == char) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
};
console.log(hasEl("I am Batman", "n"));
```

This returns 'false' when I run it, however, if I change the "n" to "I" it returns 'true'. So maybe it's only checking the first character of the string?

Thank you for your help.

Regards

Comment: Besides looping you might as well do like `str.includes(char)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 1st char is not the requested one, the `if` will fail, and the `else` block will return `false` immediately.

Move the `return false;` outside of the loop. If the char is found in the string, it will break the loop, and return `true`. If the loop ends without returning, it will return `false`.

```js
var hasEl = function(str, char) {
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == char) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  return false;
};
console.log(hasEl("I am Batman", "n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use indexOf

```
"asd".indexOf('a') >= 0
```

Comment: While this is a valid alternative it fails to explain why the original posted code fails to work.

Comment: I guess @Ori Drori  has already explained why, OP returns from function if first character is not the required one

Answer (score 0):

Better way to do this is to use .indexOf() method available on string. It will return -1 if not found

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Answer (score 0):

Are you learning programming or JS?

If you are learning JS, you can just do

```
const hasEl = (str, c) => str.includes(c);
```

The reason your code is not working because if the condition is true, the function will just return false.

You need to do

```
var hasEl = function(str, char) {
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] == char) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```js
var hasEl = function(str, char) {
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == char) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  return false;
};
console.log(hasEl("I am Batman", "n"));
```

or you can use this also

```js
var hasEl = function(str, char) {
    if (str.indexOf(char)!=-1) {
      return true;
    }
  return false;
};
console.log(hasEl("I am Batman", "n"));
```

Comment: Please take the time to explain - in your answer - how, and why, this answer works; throwing code at the OP and saying 'try this' teaches almost nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is, that it runs the `else`  or rather `retun false` statements in every round of the loop. But as soon as only one `return` statement gets executed, the whole function stops... So you could change your function as follows:

```js
var hasEl = function(str, char) {
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == char) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

However, there is a much easier way to achive the same solution:

```js
var hasEl = function(str, char) {
  if(str.indexOf(char)==-1){
    return false;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
};
```

It works using the build in `indexOf` function, which usually returns the index of a specific string (in this case only a char) inside the string the function is used as a method of. However, the function returns -1 if the char isn't found in the string. The rest should be quite self-explanatory.